# Schwalbe Marathon Plus and Micheli Protek Max: what are the fundamental differences?

Tags: tire, puncture, protection

The Schwalbe Marathon Plus and Michelin Protek Max are both tires that offer a 5mm puncture protection and a reflecting sidewall, which are both interesting features.

The price is not the same, the Marathon being the most expensive by a good margin.

What other caracteristics can be looked at to differenciate both tires? I'm thinking about rubber wear resistance or drying resistance, but the marketing put forward by both compagnies does not easily allow comparison.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Marathon Plus are an absolute pig of a tyre to fit.  Does the Protek line share this feature?   Also - I know puncture-resistant is not the same as puncture proof.

Comment: I have never ridden with a Protek tire, but I have helped someone change a tube with a pinch flat in one. It took quite a bit of work remove and reinstall, just like the Marathon Plus tires. Others have agreed when I've asked about their Protek tire installation.

Answer (score 3):

The actual differences would be known only to people who have been involved in product development or sales, and they would likely be under a NDA. So, let's speculate.

- Weight: Both are very heavy tires, but Michelin is still heavier and Marathon Plus is known to have "good enough" puncture protection.
- Construction quality: The only known fact about construction is that Protek Max has lower thread density than Marathon Plus (22 vs 67). Higher thread density usually means lower rolling resistance and smoother ride but is more expensive to produce.
- Reputation: Marathon Plus is known to be durable and to have surprisingly low rolling resistance for that kind of puncture protection. Nobody knows about Michelin yet.

All together, Michelin has to compete with price if they want to sell at all.